# Get hidden form values jquery star rating

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding the [**jQuery Star-Rating plugin**](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/).
I have many items to rate on one page, so I have added some hidden fields to each rating form.

The problem is I cannot get these values posted.

Here's an example:

```
<form method="post" id="rate" action="rate.php">
  <input name="rating" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star {split:4}" value="9.75" />
  <input name="rating" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star {split:4}" value="10.00" />
  <input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" id="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>"/>
</form>
```

The plugin uses a callback like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
      callback: function(value, link) {    
        alert("The value selected was '" + value + "'\n\nWith this callback function I can automatically submit the form with this code:\nthis.form.submit();");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

When a star is clicked I get the prompted message, that is all good, except I can't figure out how to also get the `post_id` and `ip` values.
I have tried :

```
var values = $('#rate').serialize();
alert (values);
```

However it always returns `Object Object`, it looks like only the number gets send to the function.

Is there a way to also send the other 2 fields?

Comment: I'll just add a submit button with an onclick function, it makes it a bit ugly but can't think of another way on how to do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set a name attribute for these inputs:

```
<form method="post" id="rate" action="rate.php">
  <input name="rating" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star {split:4}" value="9.75" />
  <input name="rating" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star {split:4}" value="10.00" />
  <input name="postId" type="hidden" id="post_id" value="1" />
  <input name="ip" type="hidden" id="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>"/>
</form>
```